# requests.post отдает страницу, но не ту

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, requests

Скрипт на python 3. Не могу понять, что делаю не так. В ответ на POST запрос сервер должен отдавать список закупок, а не отдает.

```
import requests

response = requests.post('https://market.mosreg.ru/Home/SearchTrade', data={'tradeName': 'экран'},  verify = False)
print(response.text)
```

UPD
Поправил код. Не помогло.

```
import requests

user_agent = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'}

session = requests.Session()
response = session.post("https://market.mosreg.ru/Home/SearchTrade", data={"tradeName":"экран"}, headers = user_agent, verify = False)
print(response.text)
```

Comment: напишите более развернутый вопрос? так, на вскидку: добавьте заголовки, User-Agent хотя бы... а лучше и Cookie с Referer заодно... UPD эндпоинт для "короб" https://api.market.mosreg.ru/api/Trade/GetTradesForParticipantOrAnonymous

Comment: Добавил User-Agent, тоже самое
А что вы имели в виду про эндпойнт, если судить по главной, то эндпойнт https://market.mosreg.ru/Home/SearchTrade именно этот путь стоит в теге action формы запроса

Comment: заработало, спасибо, дело было в том, что браузер отправляет более сложный запрос с кучей параметров, вкладка Network в панели отладка все расставила на свои места